# Add items in a DropDown element

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager, gui-extensions

Do you know hoy to add items to a dropdown?
I have the following ascx code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddComponentToBundleXPM.ascx.cs" Inherits="GUIPageViewExtension.AddComponentToBundleXPM" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.Web.UI" %>

<c:RibbonItemsGroup runat="server" ID="RibbonItemsGroup">
    <c:RibbonButton runat="server" CommandName="ViewStaging" Title="View in Staging" Label="View In Staging" ID="ViewStagingBtn" />
    <c:RibbonButton runat="server" CommandName="ViewLive" Title="View in Live" Label="View in Live" ID="ViewLiveBtn" />
    <c:Dropdown ID="listComponentTemplates" runat="server" nullable="false" />
</c:RibbonItemsGroup>
```

In codebehind, when I try to add items to this Dropdown, it doesn´t recognized this element (with ID listComponentTemplates). This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Controls;

namespace GUIPageViewExtension
{
    [ControlResources("GUIPageViewExtension.AddComponentToBundleXPM")]
    public partial class AddComponentToBundleXPM : Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionUserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                ListItem element = new ListItem("Text " + i.ToString());
                this.listComponentTemplate.
            }


        }
    }
}
```

What could be the problem? Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: your posted code here seems incomplete

Comment: Hi Sergio. Did you get to the bottom of this? It may be worth looking at the following SO question and accepted answer suggesting a recreation of the **AddComponentToBundleXPM.designer.cs** file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316757/cant-access-control-id-in-code-behind